# Vuejs 2: send event from component to parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have this code:

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  {{text}}
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<button @click="click">Click me</button>',
  methods: {
    click() {
        this.$emit('send', 'bye')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "hello"
  },
  created() {
    this.$on('send', (text) => {
        this.text = text;
    })
  }
})
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rjurado/y4yf6nve/

why event `send` does not work?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`this.$emit` only refer to Vue Components. You need to use `root` instance property to communicate with components from root instance. So basically add root to events:

```
this.$root.$emit('send', 'bye')

this.$root.$on('send', (text) => {
      this.text = text;
  })
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pss01r52/1/)

### **Vue.js central event bus**

Even better approach is to have central event bus: [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

```
var bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<button @click="click">Click me</button>',
  methods: {
    click() {
        bus.$emit('send', 'bye')
    }
  }
})
    
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "hello"
  },
  created() {
    bus.$on('send', (text) => {
        this.text = text;
    })
  }
})
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu01tdez/1/)

Answer (score 43):

Parent components can listen directly to events emitted from child components using `v-on`.

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  {{text}}
  <my-component v-on:send="sendText"></my-component>
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<button @click="click">Click me</button>',
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.$emit('send', 'bye')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "hello"
  },
  methods: {
    sendText(text) {
      alert(text)
    }
  }
})
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/y4yf6nve/2/

Answer (score 5):

For future references, custom events name can not be camelCased.
Use `this.$emit('send_event', 'bye')` instead of `this.$emit('sendEvent', 'bye')`
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4044

Comment: it is because the props as HTML defines, are always converted to lowercase! So, sendEvent becames sendevent. And that not the event is defined as, because its a string. Thats documented in VUEJS.l So v-on:sendEvent becomes v-on:sendevent. but the emit is camelCase..