# how to pass an event from a child component to a parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm studying vue js3 - I ran into a misunderstanding of linking variables in components. You need to pass the @click event from the child component, so that the value in the parent has changed.
Example:

```
children component 
 <div class="btn" id="btn" @click="addToCart(item)"> Add to cart</div>
 Parent component
 <p >{{cardValue}}</p>
```

It is necessary to increase the value of {{cardValue}} by 1 when clicking in the child component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs 2: send event from component to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156059/vuejs-2-send-event-from-component-to-parent)

Comment: This answer can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74095731/14569750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You are working on an e-commerce application where you want to add the items in a cart from a child component but cart items counter is in parent component. If Yes, Then it is necessary to `emit` an event to parent on click of `Add to cart` button, So that it will increment the counter by `1`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { createApp, ref, defineComponent } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const cartItemsCount = ref(0)

    // expose to template and other options API hooks
    return {
      cartItemsCount
    }
  }
});

app.component('item', defineComponent({
  template: '<button @click="addToCart">Add to Cart</button>',
  methods: {
    addToCart() {
        this.$emit("addToCart");
    }
  }
}));

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Items added into the cart : {{ cartItemsCount }}
  </div>
  <item @add-to-cart="cartItemsCount += 1"></item>
</div>
```